# Angular 7 paramMap not working but Snapshot working fine

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular` route parameter but my code is working with `Snapshot` and not working with `ParamMap`. Please see [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dramb).

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine both observables. I would not use a subscription inside a subscription but rather combine those observables using `flatMap`.

```
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      flatMap(params => this.myservice.myUser(params.get("id")))
    ).subscribe(user =>{
      this.myuser = user;
    })
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5crqh)

Why you shouldn't use a subscription inside a subscription find a nice article [here](https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031)

Answer (score 1):

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private myservice: UsersService
  ) {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(flatMap(params => this.myservice.myUser(params.get("id")))).subscribe(user => this.myuser = user)
  }
```

As you can see its working fine with the `paramMap`

[image]

Comment: Having a subscription inside a subscription is usually not ideal. This blog explains it quite well https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031

Comment: Yes it is working but you are now assuming that something async is running in sync. Please have a look at the article. There is a reason why there is a huge list of combining operators.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig is right working fine is not solution i am updating my answer